# Is anyone successfully using emacs to debug inner class in java?

Tags: java, vim, emacs

I currently using vim. But i found that there is not even a plugin to debug java inner class. I think emacs plugin is more powerful. So is there anyone successfully debug java inner class with emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use IntelliJ which I find to be more productive. It can has intelligent code completion, many refactoring tools and can suggest lots of ways to improve your code and make the changes for you.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/index.html?fromIndex

IMHO Just about any IDE designed for Java will be better than a general purpose editor.

Comment: for what it's worth I use both IntelliJ and Emacs (they're set to automatically synch files on any change) and switch from one to the other depending on what I'm doing.  Editing XHTML + JSTL + JavaScript: I use Emacs and is real-time NXHTML validation in "mumamo" (MUltiMAjorMOde).  Need complex macros or regexp replacement using Lisp? I use Emacs.  Need to work with "rectangle selection" or perform neat alignment: I use Emacs.  Need refactoring or debugging/tracing? I use IntelliJ IDEA.  Now my dream would be to have Emacs where IntelliJ's (pathetic) text editor is located.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear: I don't think IntelliJ's text editor is particularly bad but it's just that so far I haven't seen a single IDE nor any other "text editor" coming anywhere near close what Emacs has to offer.  If I had to choose another editor it would be vim.  And I still recommend any serious Java programmer to buy IntelliJ: I'm using it since its version 4 or so.  But when it comes to serious "text manipulation", it's not coming anywhere close to Emacs.  Which is why I use both together and get the best of both worlds ; )

Comment: I agree with the multiple editors approach and I have done the vim/intelli/eclipse combination. I used eclipse only for debugging os if its just debugging you need it for, that may be the best option.  The main reason I use IntelliJ is that it allows you to refactor code as you write it (it doesn't have to compile) and even suggests fixes for you.

Comment: But my machine is so slow that eclipse or other running in it make me quite frustrated. It's only have 2g ram and dual cpu. But i got a very powerful compile server. So i always connect to compile server with ssh and edit code and compile project in it. Everything goes well until now.

Comment: I have 32 GB on my PC but still use a Linux server via VNC as the server has 256 GB. I suggest running you IDE on the server and use the PC as a display.

Answer (score 0):

Try Eclipse, it is one of the most powerful IDE. Debug is very simple with Eclipse whereas you debugging with Emacs can be a mess